# Use Variable in SED

Tags: regex, bash, variables, sed

I cannot expand this variable in sed. I've tried everything I can think of.

I am trying to put the md5sum of file1 in line 10 of file2

I can take $x out of the regex and put some text and it works. It just will not accept the variable. printf the variable is fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
 x=$(md5sum /etc/file1)
 printf "$x \n"
 sed -i 10"s/.*/$x/g" /usr/bin/file2
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this command that uses `~` as regex delimiter instead of `/` since output of `md5sum` contains `/`:

```
sed -i "10s~.*~$x~" /usr/bin/file2
```

Comment: Hello, yes, same as I discovered... it was the output of md5sum that included /etc/file1 that was causing sed to choke. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After I reduced the variable from the md5sum output which includes the filename and directory by running $x thru:

```
x=$(echo $x | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')
```

Leaving only the MD5 it worked and quit erroring.